# Which is correct: 'pass-through' or 'passthrough' or 'pass through'?

Tags: word-choice, hyphenation

Which is correct: *pass-through* or *passthrough* or *pass through*?

I googled to find the correct wording, but found the 3 and not sure at all what is the correct one and/or there is a some domain specific rules.

I want to describe a process in which an information goes from input to output without any change.

Comment: Pass through seems what you need since PASS-THROUGH

1
: the act, action, or process of offsetting increased costs by raising prices
2
: an opening in a wall between two rooms through which something (as dishes) may be passed

Comment: Are you looking for a verb or a noun or an adjective?

Comment: does it means that the dictionary use "-" and that the 2 others version with or without space are wrong ?

Comment: That is not a [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), that is a [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without anymore context it's hard to tell exactly what you need. I would avoid using *PassThrough* unless you're actually using the [Point Cloud Library's](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php) PassThrough filter, as it may get confusing.

If you're talking about actual filters I would use *Pass-Through*. Most signal processing [filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28signal_processing%29) are hyphenated(Low-Pass, High-Pass..).

If your just describing the flow of information through some function, it should be perfeclty fine to say something like "The derived column is type cast to a/n [datatype], and the rest of the table data *passes through* the module unchanged.

Comment: Why the capitalisation for *Pass-Through*?

Comment: Good question. I'd say *Pass-through* works equaly well or even *pass-through* if he's not actually naming a filter. I have a tendency to capitalize the secondWord when naming variables.

Answer (score 9):

You found all three on Google because all three are acceptable depending on circumstances.

As a guideline -

- use *pass-through* where it is an adjective before a noun (or sometimes an object-verbal noun compound such as *egg-beater*):
  *They inspected the pass-through residue in the sediment trap.*
- use passthrough as a noun, unless this makes it too long and cumbersome:
  *He found a passthrough in the wall.*

*Pass through* is two words: *I saw him pass through a closed door.*

The principle is to maximise clarity. *A man eating shark* and *a man-eating shark* are two very different things, but *a Sunday morning service* and *a Sunday-morning service* are not so you could leave out the hyphen in the latter.